# Evaluate() something that contains a variable and a cell reference?

Tags: vba, excel

In the Evalute() function below,

- PG is a VBA defined string variable
- I Data is a sheet name

When I run the function I get error 2029.

`iNColumn = Evaluate("match('PG','I Data'!2:2,0)")`

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include double quotation marks within the criteria argument in such a way so that when the value of the variable is evaluated, it will be enclosed within the quotation marks.

Reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212167(v=office.11).aspx

`iNColumn  = Evaluate("=MATCH(""PG"",'I Data'!2:2,0)")`

Answer (score 1):

When you evaluate a custom function that has a named range in an Excel 2002 workbook, you may receive the following error message:

> Error 2029

This problem may occur if you type the following command in the Immediate window in the Visual Basic Editor and then press ENTER:

`? application.Evaluate("=SUM(xyz(),apple)")`

To work around this problem, use a Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macro to insert a formula field in a cell, and then read the value back to your macro.

For example, use a macro to insert a formula that is similar to the following in a cell in your workbook:

`=SUM(xyz(),apple)`